# Could not find cast_dual

Tags: r

[Trying to reproduce this example to learn the use of widyr](http://%20I%20am%20trying%20to%20follow%20the%20examples%20found%20here:http://uribo.github.io/rpkg_showcase/data_handling/widyr.html), I am trying to run the following code in my Rstudio IDE and encounter the following error:

> Error in function_list[k] : could not find function
>   "cast_dual"

This is the code I am trying to run:

This is my traceback Error:

```
library(pacman)
p_load(gapminder, tidyverse, widyr)

gapminder %>%   

cast_dual(country, year, lifeExp, sparse = FALSE)
```

This is my traceback error:

> Error in function_list[k] : could not find function
>   "cast_dual"
>   8. function_list[k]
>
> 7. withVisible(function_list[k])
> 8. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
> 9. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
> 10. eval(expr, envir, enclos)
> 11. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 12. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
> 13. gapminder %>% cast_dual(country, year, lifeExp, sparse = FALSE)

(Can't get the bullets right it seems)

Any help on the issue will be highly appreciated.

I have looked for this issue here and have found no clear pointers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have loaded it using the p_load() function from the pacman package.  I have also used library() prior to sending the question and got the same result.  I added the example I am trying to reproduce in the question for better reference.

Comment: It appears that function has since been removed from the `widyr` package. See [this commit](https://github.com/dgrtwo/widyr/commit/d18e1f2b19d1dfbb81ba10acb38bc7e6d8aeb6be).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Axeman.  I wonder if there would be an alternative.  Please make this an answer so I can mark it so.

Comment: @Axeman please mark this as answer